# How to Insert a json object to a column of type jsonb in Postgres using Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, jsonb

I'm trying to insert a json object to a column of type jsonb in Postgres using Slick. Here is what I have tried so far..

`implicit val attributesJsonFormat = jsonFormat1(Attribute)

implicit val attributesJsonMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Attribute, String](
    { attribute => attribute.toJson.toString() },
    { column => column.parseJson.convertTo[Attribute] }
  )`



Attribute case class..

`case class Attribute(randomVal: Int)`



Here I'm expecting Slick to do implicit conversions between reads and writes. But instead I'm getting the following error..

> column \"attributes\" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying\n  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

I assumed this error occurs because of Slick trying to save the object as a varchar.

Then I created a trigger which will call a function before a insert or update. What this function does is convert the relevant object to jsonb before saving to database.

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_attributes_to_json_in_accounts()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.attributes = to_jsonb(NEW.attributes);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_parse_attributes_to_json
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON accounts
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE parse_attributes_to_json_in_accounts();


ALTER FUNCTION parse_attributes_to_json_in_accounts() OWNER TO app;`

Even after this solution I still get the same error message. I'm guessing Slick is throwing the exception before even reaching to this point? Any idea to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is having a similar issue, you can use native sql with jsonb conversion.

```
sqlu"INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (${account.id}, (to_jsonb($jsonAttribute) #>> '{}')::jsonb)"
```

Executing the above query will insert a new record with a jsonb object to attributes column.

More information can be found here..
https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/sql.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a library that adds Slick support for many different PostgreSQL types:
https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg

Comment: Is there any workarounds without using third party libraries?

Comment: Sure, you can copy their source code. But why would you do that?

Comment: Company has strict policies when it comes to 3rd party dependencies..

Comment: Find another company.